# How to Get particular child node class name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get particular child node(i.e. class name). how can i do this. This is my code

```
    <div id="mess">
                     <h1>Bhashyam School</h1>
                        <p>AC Nagar Main Road, Nellore <br/>Ho, Nellore - 524001  </p>
                     <p class="tel">Telephone: +(91)-9603444376 </p>
                     <p class="email">Email: <a href="mailto:info@citydeal.in">info@citydeal.in</a></p>
                     <p class="web">Website: <a href="http//citydeal.in" target="new">http//citydeal.in</a></p>
                     <p class="description">Hours of Operation : 
                        Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday: 09:30 am to 10:00 pm<br>
                        Sunday: Closed , Modes of Payment : 
                        Cash
                     </p>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send.php" onsubmit="return getChilds();">
                    <p>
                        <input id="box" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"/>

                        <input type="hidden" name="strToSend" id="strToSend"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">Get SMS</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getChilds()
    {
        var arr=document.getElementById('mess').childNodes, str='';
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i].innerHTML!=undefined) {
                str+=" "+(arr[i].textContent||arr[i].innerText);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("strToSend").value=str;
        return true;
    }
    </script>
```

In the above javascript code i want childNodes with particular class names (ex:p class="tel", p class="email").

Comment: `particular child node(i.e. class name)` ??

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: .childNodes with class Names..

Comment: ar arr=document.getElementById('mess').childNodes(here i want p class1, p class2) , str=''; and what is the exact code...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery ?

```
.children(".yourClass")
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

And **as I said in comments**, without jQuery :

```
.querySelectorAll(".yourClass")
```

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/)

And because I'm the nicest person in the world, here is a working JSFiddle with `.querySelectorAll()` :

http://jsfiddle.net/F8DeQ/

(In order for you to see the result, I set your `hidden` input to `text`)

Comment: Then use `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` admits you to select multiple elements with any existing selector. Like : `document.querySelectorAll(".classname")`. I'm not going to do your work. Google it.

Comment: That's why I made it a question.

Comment: ar arr=document.getElementById('mess').childNodes(here i want p class1, p class2) , str=''; and what is the exact code...?

Comment: brother your code .querySelectorAll("p.tel") is working but i want multiple tags h1 and p without classes...?

Comment: Do it like you would do with CSS selectors : `.querySelectorAll("h1, p:not(p[class])")`

Comment: i have two p tags without classes, i want first p tag but not second p tag and both don't have a classes. ex:<p>this is p tag 1</p> & <p>this is p tag 2</p> and i want only p tag 1 in .querySelectorAll( ) not other p tags ex:p tag 2...

Comment: `querySelectorAll` gives you all occurrences of selected elements. `querySelector` gives you the first occurrence found.

Comment: Thank U Now All Working.